# Best way to run a python program from user input via a website

Tags: python, reactjs, web, execute

So I'm trying to make a website that allows users to write and execute python programs via a text area in the browser.  My front end code is written in react and I was thinking about setting up a server to basically save the input as a file and use the exec function to execute it. After doing a lot of reading I now realize how unsafe this is.  Is there a standard way of doing this? I'm very flexible as to how it's implemented.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you got a lot of work in front of you, your question is just too vague. You need a framework first.

Comment: Personally I would like to use flask, but I am really open to any type of solution.

Comment: To implement something like that anywhere near to safe you would need to have a deep inside of how Python works internally, how your OS and its isolation functionalities work (if available) and what possible attack vectors you will have to counteract. The whole topic is far too broad to be answered here.